# Efficiently check unread count on entire account

Tags: ruby, imap

To my understanding, there is no way to query an entire IMAP account for a total unread count, or the UIDs of all recent messages, regardless of mailbox. That to get a total unread count for the account, you need to iterate over all mboxes and check their status. I've done that, but it's very slow (45 seconds on one of my accounts with many mailboxes).

Mail.app can find new messages, even in deeply nested mailboxes, in just a couple seconds.

Is the speed here just a limitation of using Net::IMAP? Or am I missing some functionality that will return a more limited set of mailboxes, like only ones that have RECENT messages?

The only other option I can think of to use response handlers, and also keep a cache of which mboxes have a counter > 1, and then only check the combination of the two each cycle. But since I'm looking to do this in a script, eliminating the need to carry over a cache would be ideal, if not required.

Comment: If all else fails, you can throw [wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) on the problem and read off the wire how Mail.app does what it does.

Comment: Tracking `RECENT` probably won't help you, since a message only stays `\Recent` until a client selects the folder.  If you have another IMAP client accessing the data, `RECENT` will keep getting reset.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way to detect new messages in IMAP is via `UIDNEXT`.  Issuing

```
A001 STATUS "foldername" (UIDVALIDITY UIDNEXT)
```

on *each* folder that you care about will give you the expected next UID for that folder.  [Here's what the RFC has to say](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.1.1):

> Unique identifiers
> are assigned in a strictly ascending fashion in the mailbox; as each
> message is added to the mailbox it is assigned a higher UID than the
> message(s) which were added previously.  Unlike message sequence
> numbers, unique identifiers are not necessarily contiguous.
>
> The next unique identifier value is the predicted value that will be
> assigned to a new message in the mailbox.  Unless the unique
> identifier validity also changes (see below), the next unique
> identifier value MUST have the following two characteristics.  First,
> the next unique identifier value MUST NOT change unless new messages
> are added to the mailbox; and second, the next unique identifier
> value MUST change whenever new messages are added to the mailbox,
> even if those new messages are subsequently expunged.

So just keep track of the each folder's expected next UID and UID validity value.  If a `STATUS` command results in either `UIDNEXT` or `UIDVALIDITY` changing from your cached value, you know you need to check for new mail (if the former) or resync (if the latter).

[Something like this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/classes/Net/IMAP.html#M001437):

```
imap.status("foldername", ["UIDNEXT", "UIDVALIDITY"])
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something. If I need to keep track of one of the UIDs for each mailbox, and then check each mailbox for changes each time, what am I saving by doing it this way? How is it better than not caching anything, and still iterating over each box on each refresh and just returning a count? Are the UID status returns significantly faster than RECENT?

Comment: @farski: `STATUS` is generally much faster (and pretty much always no slower) than `SELECT`.  And checking `RECENT` probably won't help you, since a message only stays `\Recent` until a client selects the folder. If you have another IMAP client accessing the data, `RECENT` will keep getting reset to 0.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `UNSEEN`. All I've ever been trying is `STATUS`, never `SELECT`. I'm going through the Ruby standard library net/imap, and simply making a connection, listing the boxes and then getting the `STATUS` `COUNT`. If all I do is the list, it takes 2 seconds. If I add the status it takes about 50 seconds.

Comment: @farski: Slow IMAP servers are slow IMAP servers -- nothing much you can do about it.  And again, you really want `UIDNEXT`.  `COUNT` will stymie you when messages are both added and removed from a folder; `UNSEEN` doesn't help when new messages are marked read.  `UIDNEXT` was designed for exactly your problem.  Note that if your IMAP server advertises [the `LIST-STATUS` capability](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5819), you can query status for all the folders at once...